# disable global css for element id

Tags: css

I have a `calendar.css` file that contains the rule `#calendar`.

The calendar.css file has some `table` classes.

Problem: I want to apply the following CSS to all tables in the app, except the ones that are called by `#calendar`

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1050px) {
    table {
        overflow-x: auto;
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Comment: could you give as an example html structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the not-construct in CSS:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_not.asp

So for example:

```
:not(table#calendar) {
    background: #ff0000;
}
```

Comment: Please provide more info than just link (that may not work in future)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following CSS:

```
table:not(#calendar) {
    overflow-x: auto;
    display: block;
}
```

More info on `:not` selector [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_not.asp)

Answer (score 1):

This rule is less specific than `#calendar` so it will always be applied to all tables, but be overwritten by `#calendar` rule.

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Answer (score 1):

You can use not() pseudo to do that like following:

```
/*table*/
@media screen and (max-width: 1050px) {
/*@media screen and (max-width: 750x) {*/
    table:not(#calendar) {
        overflow-x: auto;
        display: block;
    }
}
```